# How can i store any printed output to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposedly, i have a printed output : 2, 3 , 4, 5.....10 etc,
How do i store this in the form of dataframe?
Desired Output:

output

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Can somebody help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the output has a string (and in the format you showed) you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = output.split(",") # gives you a list
df = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=["output"])
```

You can convert the column from string to int by doing the following:

```
df.output.astype("int")
```

Comment: Hi, could you also let me know,if there are multiple columns what would be the syntax? i m sorry i am just new to this so, thank you so much.  @DPM

Comment: Each column would come from different prints? Also could you accept the answer please